# Visual Studio will not connect to Sql Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ado.net

I am no longer able to graphically see tables, server or databases in Visual Studio 2008. If I open previously created datasets all I see is the XML as if I had selected view code instead of designer, I have also lost my server explorer window and when I try to re-add it from tools --> connect to server or database nothing happens. 
Nothing was installed before or after this issue appeared. Please offer any suggestions.

Current relevant environment:

- OS: Windows XP SP3
- IDE: Visual Studio 2008 SP1
- SQL: Sql Server 2000

Comment: had u try display the window from view->windows->Server explorer

Comment: Same Result as anyother method

Comment: So were you able to see them before with VS 2008 or has this been a problem since you installed it?

Comment: I was able to see them on friday no problem and as stated above when I try to view the previously created datasets (by me) it opens them via an xml editor only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by restoring computer turns out a lot issues were starting to cascade and I hads to restore the whole computer to an earlier state.

Answer (score 1):

Silly question, but I hit this a lot. If you're running Vista with UAC enabled and the SQL box is localhost, you have to start VS2008 as administrator to open the connection.